# Display data as georeferenced using three matrices of lat / long / data?

Tags: arcmap, georeferencing

I have a 12 x 12 matrix of data and two more matrices of corresponding latitude and longitude.

Is there a way I can import the data as a georeferenced raster in ArcMap?

For example, in Matlab, plotting pcolor(lon,lat,data) would project the data correctly. I have tried and failed to save the file as a geotiff in other software, so I must try now to display it in this way.

Comment: What software are you using? This can be done in Python using Rasterio (or just straight GDAL I imagine) as well as in R.

Comment: Please decide which of QGIS or ArcGIS Desktop or something else you wish to ask about in this particular question.  That way you can tell us precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck with it.  You can always ask about the other(s) in a separate question.